# Why is my simple code taking so much time to execute when i give in large numbers as input?

Tags: python-3.x, time-complexity

I have written a simple code to print the largest prime factor of a given number from Project Euler. It works just fine for numbers like 24, but there is no response from the python shell for large numbers!

```
a=600851475143
b=[]
for i in range(2,600851475143):
    if a%i==0:
         if i==2:
            b.append(i)
            continue
         for j in range(2,i+1):
             if j==i:
                b.append(i)
             if i%j==0:
                break
 print(max(b))
 print(b)
```

Comment: This program runs on the order of 10^20 operations. The average computer can do around 10^8 operations per second (usually closer to 10^7 in python since python is a very slow language). Therefore, this program would take 10^13 seconds to complete, which is a long time

Comment: To finish that train of thought, 10^13 seconds is approximately 316,887 years.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an algorithm like this to get large factors of prime numbers:

```
import math

def LLL(N):
   p = 1<<N.bit_length()-1
   if N == 2:
     return 2
   if N == 3:
     return 3
   s = 4
   M = pow(p, 2) - 1
   for x in range (1, 100000):
     s = (((s * N ) - 2 )) % M
     xx = [math.gcd(s, N)] + [math.gcd(s*p+x,N) for x in range(7)] + [math.gcd(s*p-x,N) for x in range(1,7)]
     try:
        prime = min(list(filter(lambda x: x not in set([1]),xx)))
     except:
        prime = 1
     if prime == 1:
        continue
     else:
        break
   return N/prime
```

Comment: This is not what OP actually asked. Additionally, OP is trying to solve a problem on Project Euler. If this works this is a huge spoiler.